# Where to add log4j configuration file in our project?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, netbeans

I have implemented log4j in my web application project. Project is done using net beans,using  tomcat 7.0.41. At first,I created log4j.property file and placed under web page->Web-INF->classes->log4j.properties in net beans and it asks me to locate the file in my project,so I manually located that file to implement log4j in my application. After that I changed the place of the log4j.properties file to myproject->build->web->WEB_INF->classes->log4j.properties in location of my project saved, now its working fine, it did not ask me to manually locate the property file, It takes automatically when my class files executed. Now my problem is that once I committed the project and again checkout the project on some day, property file does not appear and it again ask for property file. So where can I create the log4j property file in my project so that my team mates can utilize it when they checkout project in their system.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you put `log4j.properties` to `src/main/resources/` and it will be copied to the right place by the build process.

Answer (score 0):

I never use net beans, but I think put log4j.properties under `Classpath` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how Net Beans handels this, but i think that the "build" directory is where the "compiled" project is put to.

So i would not recommend to put any files there which should be versioned because mostly those directories are ignored for versioning ( see .gitignore files for example when using git).

Resources like property files should be within the sources and your IDE should copy them to the correct place when building the project.